# pytest profiling mostly reporting on pytest functions

Tags: python, pytest, profiling

In order to profile my code, I've installed `pytest-profiling` and run

```bash
$ pytest --profile
```

However, almost all of the results in the summary are related to functions in pytest itself:

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
      159    0.001    0.000    0.170    0.001 runner.py:108(pytest_runtest_protocol)
      159    0.001    0.000    0.143    0.001 runner.py:116(runtestprotocol)
...
2615/1749    0.015    0.000    0.131    0.000 _callers.py:9(_multicall)
...
```

Is there a way to get the profiler to ignore pytest's functions and get instead the stats for my package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There currently appears to be no option in the plugin to cutomize which function calls are shown (source: [plugin repo](https://github.com/man-group/pytest-plugins/blob/5f9b88a65a8c1e506885352bbd9b2a47900f5014/pytest-profiling/pytest_profiling.py#L91)).

However, you could write a custom script to display only the profiling results you're interested in (which is saved at `./prof/combined.prof`).

```py
import pstats

stats = pstats.Stats('./prof/combined.prof')
stats.print_stats("path/to/function_calls/you/want/to/show")

# Or alternatively
stats.print_stats("local_path", 20) # Only show 20 of the listings
stats.sort_stats('cumulative').print_stats('dir_name', 20) # Sort by cumulative time
```

You can then write a script (`.sh`, `.bat`, ...) which calls `pytest --profile` followed by the above code snippet.

For more information on pstats: https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html